# Parsing Newline delimited JSON file in spark not producing output

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The Newline delimited JSON file sample looks as below.

```
[
    {"name": "Vishay Electronics", 
    "specifications": " feature low on-resistance and high Zener switching speed\n1/lineup from small signal products to 800V high voltage products\n3  MOSFETs are highly reliable\nstandard AEC-Q101\n package lineup flexibly meets the requirements of various in-vehicle systems.",
     "url": "https://www.mouser.in/", 
     "image": "https://www.mouser.in/", 
     "downtime": "11PT",
     "inputvolt": "8", 
     "date": "2013-04-01", 
     "upTime": "15M", 
     "description": " feature low on-resistance and high zener speed\n1/lineup from small signal products to 800V high voltage products\n3  MOSFETs are highly reliable\nstandard AEC-Q101\n package lineup flexibly meets the requirements of various in-vehicle systems."
     },
     
     {"name": "Vishay Electronics", 
    "specifications": " feature low on-resistance and high zener speed\n1/lineup zener from small signal products to 800V high voltage products\n3  MOSFETs are highly reliable\nstandard AEC-Q101\n package lineup flexibly meets the requirements of various in-vehicle systems.",
     "url": "https://www.mouser.in/", 
     "image": "https://www.mouser.in/", 
     "downtime": "5PT",
     "inputvolt": "8", 
     "date": "2013-04-01", 
     "upTime": "15M", 
     "description": " feature low on-resistance and high switching speed\n1/lineup from small signal products to 800V high voltage products\n3  MOSFETs are highly reliable\nstandard AEC-Q101\n package lineup flexibly meets the requirements of various in-vehicle systems."
     },
     
     {"name": "Vishay Electronics", 
    "specifications": " feature low on-resistance and high switching speed\n1/lineup from small signal products to 800V high voltage products\n3  MOSFETs are highly reliable\nstandard AEC-Q101\n package lineup flexibly meets the requirements of various in-vehicle systems.",
     "url": "https://www.mouser.in/", 
     "image": "https://www.mouser.in/", 
     "downtime": "2PT",
     "inputvolt": "8", 
     "date": "2013-04-01", 
     "upTime": "15M", 
     "description": " feature low on-resistance and high switching speed\n1/lineup from small signal products to 800V high voltage products\n3  MOSFETs are highly reliable\nstandard AEC-Q101\n package lineup flexibly meets the requirements of various in-vehicle systems."
     }
     
     
    ]
```

When i validate JSON online at `https://jsonlint.com/`
it looks ok.

[image]

When i read file in spark and printschema...it seems fine.

[image]

Here is the problem.

When i run the below code it is producing 0 output, instead of giving 2 records.

Code.

```
    val df = spark.read.option("multiLine", true).json("D:/bittu/testmyjson.json")
    df.printSchema()
   df.filter($"specifications".contains("%zener%")).show(truncate = false)
```

But not working properly.

[image].

How can we handle such scenario.... Kindly share your thoughts.
Appreciate your comment very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of contains use **`.like`** or using **`contains`** remove **`%`** (as contains checks for substring and there is no data having **%** followed/prepended by zener)

```
df.filter($"specifications".like("%zener%")).show(truncate = false)

//using contains remove %
df.filter($"specifications".like("%zener%")).show(truncate = false)

/*
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------+---------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------+
|date      |description                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |downtime|image                 |inputvolt|name              |specifications                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |upTime|url                   |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------+---------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------+
|2013-04-01| feature low on-resistance and high switching speed
1/lineup from small signal products to 800V high voltage products
3  MOSFETs are highly reliable
standard AEC-Q101
 package lineup flexibly meets the requirements of various in-vehicle systems.|5PT     |https://www.mouser.in/|8        |Vishay Electronics| feature low on-resistance and high zener speed
1/lineup zener from small signal products to 800V high voltage products
3  MOSFETs are highly reliable
standard AEC-Q101
 package lineup flexibly meets the requirements of various in-vehicle systems.|15M   |https://www.mouser.in/|
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------+---------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------+
*/
```

For **case insensitive match** use `lower` function on specifications column then do **`like or contains`** filter

**`Example:`**

```
df.filter(lower($"specifications").like("%zener%")).select("specifications").show(false)

df.filter(lower($"specifications").contains("zener")).select("specifications").show(false)

/*
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|specifications                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| feature low on-resistance and high Zener switching speed
1/lineup from small signal products to 800V high voltage products
3  MOSFETs are highly reliable
standard AEC-Q101
 package lineup flexibly meets the requirements of various in-vehicle systems.|
| feature low on-resistance and high zener speed
1/lineup zener from small signal products to 800V high voltage products
3  MOSFETs are highly reliable
standard AEC-Q101
 package lineup flexibly meets the requirements of various in-vehicle systems.    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
*/
```

Comment: In question your expected output is 2 count, for that case i have edited the answer now, Please check it once..

Comment: as specification contain sentence with ",", will it affect if i write output to .csv....kindly suggest.

Comment: Try with `df.filter(lower($"specifications").like("%zener%"))`..

Comment: spark encloses string column data in quotes, for more documentation around writing as csv files take a look into https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/read-csv.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220049/discussion-between-rashmi-ghosh-and-484).